# using compareTo with maps in java

Tags: java, maps

I want to find the max min and average values of numbers in a map. value x is the map, and the keys are module codes and the values are the students marks.

So far i've only managed to remove any students who have the value -1, which means they didn't take the module. however i know you cant use greater than or less than. but i'm not sure how to get around it, i've tried casting to ints but that doesn't work.

I've read about and seen 'compare to' methods help but i'm not to sure how to use that with this example. here is what i'm doing at the minute.the [0] is the module in the map, as there are many items in the map,

I will later want a loop to have i and increase i, to find the max min and average for every module, but at the minute i'm just trying to find the values for one module.

```
public class Stats {
   public static Map<String, Integer> x;


   public static void get() {
    int min=101;
    int max = 0;
    x = Student.marks;


    if (!x.values().toArray()[0].equals(-1)) {
        System.out.println(x.keySet().toArray()[0]);
        System.out.println(x.values().toArray()[0]);

    }


}
```

Comment: Map<String, Integer> means : one module <==> one mark ?, so can't be able to get "max min and average" for each module because you have only one mark, you should have Map<String, List<Integer>> to do it

Comment: this is very unclear ... what does "x" represent here ? its keys and its values ? Is "x" for one student ? I don't understand why there is only one mark, because if it's the average so you don't need to find it but if it's not it's strange to have one mark/module (but maybe it's the case but you won't have an "average")

Comment: @azro i cant change it as it messes up a lot more stuff in different classes. the map is created in a loop, and every line has a map for a different student, so there's many maps of modules and scores, i'm accessing the maps first item so i should be able to compare the values? x is just one map, full of many keys and values, toarray[0] is the first item in every map. every map has the same amount of keys and values, and if a student does not take that module, they have -1 as the value.

Comment: please answer questions to help .. is it the situation : "x" is for ONE student, and he has a:  Map<moduleName, markForTheModule> ?

Comment: yep! x is one student , it looks like - student 1{module 1: 5, module 2:-1, module3:10} so at the minute im just printing every students mark from the first module in the map if that student takes that module

Comment: If you want to have min, max, and average for each module, you need ALL students data, and not only one as you're showing us here, with this code you can only have the max and min of ONE student

Comment: @azro  i have all the students marks for this module trust me, this is definitely printing all marks for the module, i'm calling this method in a loop that reads the original input and splits the lines. then later i just change 0 to, i in a loop with i++ that will do this for every module in the map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136621/discussion-between-azro-and-sb33).